# How to find the count of a particular class with a particular style is repeated in a HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page, where I have two div classes :

```
<i class="fas fa-info-circle float-left resultsInfo"  style="color: red; padding-top: 4px;" ></i>

<i class="fas fa-info-circle float-left resultsInfo" ></i>
```

On Page load, I need to get the count of how many times these each Div has been repeated.  The only differentiating factor between these two div is the style. So I wanted to know how many times the first div oocured and how many times the second one. Please help me to find this out. I am new to HTML and js

Comment: Where are these divs? And why do you have so many questions where you haven't accepted an answer?

Comment: @ControlAltDel - Sorry If I havent accepted answer, there wont be any answers given to that question. For those questions which have answers, I have accepted answers too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is this:

```
<html>
    <body>

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <ul>
<i class="count fas fa-info-circle float-left resultsInfo"  style="color: red; padding-top: 4px;" ></i>
<i class="count fas fa-info-circle float-left resultsInfo" ></i>
    </ul>

 </body> 
 </html>
```

and js is lookin like

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "count: " + document.querySelectorAll('.count').length;
```

here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/f7tsLcrd/

Comment: I think OP wants to count them seperately. As in, count the ones with just the classes and count the ones with the classes and the inline styles. This is a bit more clear if you read the title of the question carefully.

Comment: Yes @icecub, For the two div's there is no other differentiating factor other than styling. So I want to get the count of how many times the first div occuring and how many times the second one.

Answer (score 2):

This snippet returns the number of elements that have a "count" class and red color

```
$(".count").filter(function() {
return ($(this).prop('style').color == 'red');
}).length
```

Comment: how to print the output in console for the above fnction ? @Moslem_nh

Comment: save result in a variable and place it into cosole.log() or place all above code in console.log() @wanderors